# Transform JS collection to an object with specific keys and grouped values

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, collections, grouping

I would like to create this JS function with these arguments:

```
transform([{a:1, b:'1', c:true},{a:'1', b:2, c:3, d:false}, {a:1, c:'test'}], ['a','b','c']);
```

First argument is an array of objects

Second one is array of keys.

I would like to get this output object:

```
{a:[1, '1', 1], b:['1', 2],c:[true, 3, 'test']}
```

As you can see the second argument became the keys to the created object
and all values under these keys where grouped together.

And maybe an option to pass a unique argument to function and get this (duplicate values removed):

```
{a:[1, '1'], b:['1', 2], c:[true, 3, 'test']}
```

What is the fast and/or elegant way to do it?

Is there any lodash/underscore helper for it?

As an additional generalism. How can the input (the first argument) be a generic collection with nested levels (array or object of nested levels of arrays or objects) ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
function transform(data,keys){
  let results = {};
  //loop all you keys
  keys.forEach(index => {
      //loop your arrays
      data.forEach(element => {
          //if there is a match add the key to the results object
          if(index in element) {
             if(!(index in results))  results[index] = [];   
             //check if a value already exists for a given key.    
             if(!(element[index] in results[index]))   results[index].push(element[index]);
          }
      });
  });
  return results;
}

console.log(transform([{a:1,b:'1',c:true},{a:'1',b:2,c:3,d:false},{a:1,c:'test'}], ['a','b','c']));
```

Comment: What if I need the input (the first argument) to be a generic n-depth nested collection?

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over the key array and pass this key to another function which will use `forEach` method. This `getMatchedKeyValues` using `forEach`will return an array of elements whose key matches

```js
var arr = [{
  a: 1,
  b: '1',
  c: true
}, {
  a: '1',
  b: 2,
  c: 3,
  d: false
}, {
  a: 1,
  c: 'test'
}];
var keys = ['a', 'b', 'c']

function transform(keyArray) {
  var newObj = {};
  // looping over key array
  keyArray.forEach(function(item) {
    // adding key property and calling a function which will return
    // an array of elements whose key is same
    newObj[item] = getMatchedKeyValues(item)
  })
  return newObj;
}

function getMatchedKeyValues(keyName) {
  var valArray = [];
  arr.forEach(function(item) {
    if (item[keyName]) {
      valArray.push(item[keyName])
    }
  })
  return valArray;
}
console.log(transform(keys))
```

Comment: What if I need the input (the first argument) to be a generic n-depth nested collection?

Comment: @mov but your initial question does not include that

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```
let param1 = [{a:1,b:'1',c:true},{a:'1',b:2,c:3,d:false},{a:1,c:'test'}];
let param2 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

function test(objArr, keys) {
  let returnObject = {};
  keys.forEach(key => returnObject[key] = []);

  return objArr.reduce((ret, obj) => {
    keys.forEach(key => {
      if (obj[key] !== undefined)
        ret[key].push(obj[key]);
    });
    return ret;
  }, returnObject);
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(test(param1, param2)));
```

Outputs:

```
{"a":[1,"1",1],"b":["1",2],"c":[true,3,"test"]}
```

Comment: What if I need the input (the first argument) to be a generic n-depth nested collection?

Answer (score 0):

I coded below , pls have a look this solution.

```js
function test(arr, arr1) {
  return arr.reduce((total, current) => {
    arr1.forEach(curr => {
      if (typeof total[curr] === "undefined") total[curr] = [];
      if (current[curr]) total[curr].push(current[curr]);
    });
    return total;
  }, {});
}
console.log(
  test(
    [
      { a: 1, b: "1", c: true },
      { a: "1", b: 2, c: 3, d: false },
      { a: 1, c: "test" }
    ],
    ["a", "b", "c"]
  )
);
```

Comment: What if I need the input (the first argument) to be a generic n-depth nested collection?